# iOS loss of image quality

Tags: objective-c, image

This is the case:

I have an image. In the projects browser it looks good.
/but when I 'load' it in one of my controls the edges get rather blurry. And I'm not resizing it or anything. Why is this?

The image, unloaded:

[image: normal image]

The image when loaded in a control:

[image: blurry edges]

As you can see the corners get rather blurry/streched. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happened to me in the past.
Most of the time the problem is that the dimensions of the image are different from the dimensions of the controller.

Check you controller size with:

```
   NSLog(@"controller size = %@",NSStringFromRect(your_controller.rect));
```

And see if it the image size fits.

Comment: @Xtudio Are you sure it's not stretched as shannoga says? If I take the original image, which is 56px across, and stretch it to be the width of the entire switch in the second image, which is 93px, then I get exactly the same effect on the corners.

Answer (score 3):

I've also had this before and as @shannoga said if the dimensions of the view are different to the image it will auto stretch it.

Are you loading the image into an ImageView?  if so the imageView.Mode property defaults to Scale To Fill. If you set the mode to Top, Left or Center it wont stretch the image.